# ready for use bash tool to export/import JCEKS secret keys

Tags: java, openssl, keystore, secret-key, jceks

I work with a tool that creates system backup. The backup contains passwords as well. The backup tool uses a `secret key` stored in a `JCEKS` keystore to decrypt/encrypt the passwords saved in the backup file.

I know that I can generate secret key and add it to `JCEKS` keystore with `keytool` this way:

```
$ keytool -genseckey -alias "key-alias" -keyalg AES -keysize 128 \
  -storetype jceks -keystore "/path/to/keystore.jceks" \
  -storepass:file "/path/to/.storepass" \
  -keypass:file "/path/to/.keypass"
```

Before I run the backup tool, I need to generate my own `secret key`. That part works fine, I am able to create a backup file with encrypted passwords.

I have a docker environment and the image I use contains a default installation of an app. During the first container start, I need to add the same `secret key` to the `JCEKS` keystore in the docker container that I used when I created the backup, and then I can run my restore process that configures the app running in the container.

I would like to have a tool to export/import the `secret key` from bash. I have found some solutions on StackOverflow and other places, but they suggest using a Java program, like [this](https://dzone.com/articles/secret-key-import-java).

But I would like to have a ready for use tool without java.
Is there any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have created a command-line tool that I can use.
That tool I have cleated is an open-source tool so everyone can use and improve.

This is the URL of the CLI tool: [jceks-tool](https://github.com/zappee/jceks-tool)